# Getting the, NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for #<RSpec.. but have controller type specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller, specifications

I'm using RSpec 3.2.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SimulationsController, :type => :controller do
    context "GET #index" do 
        it "populates an array of simulations" do 
            simulation = FactoryGirl.build(:simulation)
            get :index
            response.should render_template :index
        end 
    end
end
```

I have the controller type specified and am still receiving this error, is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your `spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: Literally just fixed it, needed 'require 'rspec/rails''

Comment: Great! Add it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding

```
require 'rspec/rails'
```

to my spec_helper.rb, as such:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Deals with being unable to find 'get' function
  require 'rspec/rails'
end
```